# Data table in one visualization automatically changes based on map layer

Tags: spotfire, dynamic-tables

In Spotfire, is it possible or is there an R script I can use that will make the data table in one visualization automatically change based upon the marker layer's data table in a map visualization?

Comment: please specify your need. Do you really want to change the data table, or its selection? Or are you looking for a calculated column? "based upon the marker layer's data table" - again based on its selection / properties...?

Comment: @MátéJuhász - I have map in the upper visualization and a data table visualization below it. If I have Table 1, 2, 3...7 as marker layers in the map and then select Table 3 in the map, then the lower data table visualization changes to Table 3. Maybe "changes" is the wrong word. Basically, make one visualization's selection become selected based upon the table selection in a map visualization.

Comment: Has anyone done this before? In Spotfire, let's say Vis1 = map visualization and Vis2 = table visualization. I click on a marker layer in Vis1 and Vis2's table changes to that same data table.